# Вывод новостей на сайт

Tags: php

Столкунулся с двумя проблемами:

1. Выводит новости все кроме последней:

   ```
   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
   $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_bd');
   mysqli_query($connect ," SET NAMES 'utf8' ");
   $result = mysqli_query($connect , " SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC ");
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

   mysqli_close($connect);

   while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   ?>

   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="cols col-5">

     <h1><?php echo $row['title'] ?></h1>
     <p><?php echo $row['text_preview'] ?></p>
     <p><?php echo $row['date'] ?></p>
     <p><?php echo $row['time'] ?></p>
     <p><?php echo $row['author'] ?></p>
     <a href="/myblog/auth/news.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><button>Читать полностью</button></a>
     <a href="/myblog/auth/edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><button>Редактировать новость</button></a>
     <a href="/myblog/auth/delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><button>Удалить новость</button></a>

   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <?php } ?>
   ```
2. Как лучше реальизовать превью новости, а при нажатии на кнопку меня переводило на страницу с полным текстом

Я хотел при создании таблицы создать ячейку для такого текста и вводить его при создании новости отдельно. Есть ли какой то более мудрый способ???

Comment: 1. Уберите присвоение $row = ... До цикла while

Comment: 2. Это и есть более мудрый способ, т.к. При создании автоматических превью, у вас должно возникнуть как минимум 2 вопроса что туда должно попасть, а что не должно. Самый банальный способ обрезать строку по длине но вы же не хотите получить в конце превью половину слова за которой следует "..." Соответственно вам прийдется заморочиться с разбиением по словам и ещё лучше по предложениям. Поэтому лучший вариант пускай контент менеджер заполняет и основную статью и превью, так он человек будет решать как будет выглядеть превью.

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло!